# R - Convert to time values after group_by

Tags: r

I have a column in a dataframe, `chr` and in the form `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`. I have no problem converting them to `POSIXct`. However, if I leave that column as `chr` and after I use `group_by` with that column as the first column of the new dataframe, I cannot convert that first column to `POSIXct` any more

R says `do not know how to convert 'abc[, 1]' to class “POSIXct”`. I check the structure of the new dataframe and the first column is still `chr`. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: While SO users are generally imaginative a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would greatly help

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing the conversion; and then, use `group_by` to group the variables. I have grouped date variables many times without problem.

[`lubridate`](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/10/the-team-data-science-process.html) is another package from the `tidyverse`, it makes easier work with dates and times.